# Fastest way to find object in nested array/object

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array of objects who also have an array on one property:

```
const boards = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Lorem ipsum',
    tasks: [
      { id: 42, ... },
      { id: 65, ... },
      { id: 24, ... },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Lorem ipsum',
    tasks: [
      { id: 12, ... },
      { id: 85, ... },
      { id: 14, ... },
    ],
  },
];
```

I'm looking for the **best** and **most efficient** way to find the index of a `task` (and the board of where it's in of course). I came up with the following but I wonder if this is really the most efficient way when looking for the `task`, especially when you have a large dataset, or if there may be a better way to search through?

In my special case there won't be many boards (most of the time not more then 10, but there may be hundreds of tasks)

```
const idToFind = 1;

let boardIndex = null;
let taskIndex = null;

boards.some((board, index) => {
  taskIndex = board.tasks.findIndex(task => task.id === idToFind);

  // if it has found the task, assign board index and end lookup
  if (taskIndex > -1) {
    boardIndex = index;
    return true;
  }

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new lookup table of tasks and their associated index inside `boards`:

```
var taskIds = {
  12: 1,
  85: 1,
  14: 1,
  42: 0,
  65: 0,
  24: 0
};
```

From there, finding a task and associated board is only `O(1)` * 2

Example using Lodash:

```
var taskIds = {};
_.each(boards, function(board, index) {
  _.each(board.tasks, function(task) {
    taskIds[task.id] = index;
  });
});
```

Now you can easily find a board by task index in constant time:

`boards[taskIds[65]]`