# Fastest way to "reduce" nested array to object with keys + fastest way to find by key

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, performance, reduce

I need to transform this type of nested array to be able to search by key (id) fastest way possible:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"example1",
      "items":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"example1",
      "items":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

In reality there is much more nested arrays (about 4 levels).

My current way is to do `reduce` of every level and then I can use for example `list[1].items[1].name`. This looks like very slow and inefficient way to me.

I also found here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650166/fastest-way-to-find-object-in-nested-array-object) that I can create lookup table `id->index` but this looks like it have same complexity and eats more memory.

Does someone have better idea to do such transformation? I am working with huge data sets and I am starting to feel I need to find better way to process data.

I am doing this because I need to search in this data set by ID quickly. Searching in array by `findIndex` is slow. And transformation needs processing as I described above.

I need to find option with lowest overall complexity.

Comment: `id` appears at multiple levels, in which one are you interested in ?

Comment: Lookup table is indeed the way to go. Please show why this does not work well enough for you. Add some code to your question, so we can see how you implemented it, and where there might be an issue. Transformation you do only once, and have the gain from it with *every* search. So the cost is worth it.

Comment: let's say you want to find id=1, there are two places id=1 appear, which one is suppose to get?

Comment: @sam id is unique on given level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for the transformation. It is an effort that is worth the cost, because you'll benefit from that investment with *every* search you do.

Here is a transformation into a `Map` based lookup table for retrieving the associated object. It will take a comma separated string of id-values as look-up key:

```js
function makeLookup(list, map=new Map, prefix="") {
    for (let obj of list) {
        map.set(prefix + obj.id, obj);
        if (obj.items) makeLookup(obj.items, map, prefix + obj.id + ",");
    }
    return map;
}


let list = [{ "id":1, "name":"example1", "items":[
     {"id":1, "name":"example2", "example":123},
     {"id":2, "name":"example3", "example":123}
  ]}, { "id":2, "name":"example4", "items":[
     { "id":3, "name":"example5", "example":123 },
     { "id":4, "name":"example6", "example":123 }
  ]}
];

// One-shot transformation
let lookup = makeLookup(list);

// Demo of a loookup
console.log(lookup.get("1,2").name);
console.log(lookup.get("2,3").example);
```

Comment: Isn't that very memory inefficient because `.get(1)` will still have `items` array in it?

Comment: It will have that array, but that is your original data. It is not a copy of it. So this Map is like an index on top of it. If you want, you can delete those arrays but it will take extra time, and it will affect you original structure. Again, it is not a copy.